# Remove Card from CardScrollView

Tags: java, android, google-glass

I have a CardScrollView with four Cards and when the user does a tap, it shows up a menu with an option saying : "Delete card". 
Then when the user does a tap again, it has to delete the current card and goes to the next card.

This is easy to understand if we see the "Take a picture" app, when you take a picture is a card and then you tap for see the menu and select "Delete". It deletes the image and jumps to the next picture.

Not sure how it's working in the Take a picture app so I'm not able to recreate the same effect in my app.

I'm using a List for holding the cards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a Card from a CardScrollView :

Imagine you have a list of Cards (mCards) and a class that extends CardScrollAdapter (adapter).

```
mCards.remove(currentCard);     // Remove the current card selected from the list of Cards
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify the adapter that needs to update the data
```